# Could not log in the ubuntu 16.04 after installing the nvidia geforce drive

Tags: 16.04, nvidia

I installed an nvidia driver (340, my display card is GTX970) but I could not log in to Ubuntu afterwards. I get a black screen after logging in. When I enter a tty, in the login part, it will continue showing:

```
None of the NVIDIA graphics adapters were initialized
Nvidia init module failed
```

As a result, I could not type any command in the tty.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here is what I did:
Enter the terminal command line by 
Ctrl-Alt-F1. Purged all nvidia drivers

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then I renamed the .Xauthority in`/home/username/`

```
mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak
```

Then reboot and it worked fine. Hope that works for you too